# How to detect user browser (firefox, chrome,...) in 2023

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent

I'm searching for a way to detect on which browser the client is in Javascript. I have seen a lot of articles using `navigator.useragent`. But it seems that this way is not recommanded and deprecated nowadays.

I cannot find another way of achieving this. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `navigator.useragent` is not deprecated at all

Comment: Client can spoof `useragent` value, why would you need to know the browser?

Comment: because .sort() method in js doesn't work the same on Firefox and Chrome. I need to figure out on what browser the user is to adapt the method output....

Comment: why do you say `sort()` works differently on FF and Chrome?

Comment: Well, browser sniffing definely isn't a solution, it's better to fix your sorting instead. (Some sorting algorithms have treated null values differently (not sure if that's relevant in 2023), the fix is to replace the null values before sorting.)

Comment: @GrafiCode here are some articles I've seen https://support.piano.io/hc/en-us/articles/8264571061138-Client-Hints-User-Agent-deprecation-, https://developer.chrome.com/blog/user-agent-reduction-deprecation-trial/

Comment: here's what MDN says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent full support on every major browser

Comment: The traditional problem with programmers doing browser sniffing instead of feature detection is that as new browsers come to the market, or implement new features, sites stop working for no good reason, and browser vendors are forced to fake their identity.

Comment: @GrafiCode the el1, and el2 in the sort method => .sort(el1, el2) are not the same. you can check with this example ```const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,,7,8,9,10]

array.sort((el1, el2 )=>{
  console.log(el1)
    console.log(el2)
})```

Comment: result of `sort()` function is the same on chrome and ff: https://jsfiddle.net/nq0sog96/ `[1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, undefined]`

Comment: So, the problem you want to address is that browsers may use different algorithms to produce the same final result? Are you willing to compile and maintain a list of JavaScript runtimes? What are you trying to do that relies on the exact algorithm?

Comment: What? In what world would the `a` and `b` in a sort method _be the same_? How do you compare things if they are just the same? Do you mean a `null` value isn't treated the same or something? If this was the case I hope I would have heard of this years ago as this is not a known problem.

Comment: @GrafiCode If you'll run the test in a very ancient Chrome, you'll get `undefined` first (This is exactly what I referred to in my first comment).

Comment: Classic XY problem.   If you have a problem with `sort` then run a routine *to detect that*.  eg provide a known input that gives a known output - if it's that output then you know which browser it is - or, more specifically (and more usefully) you know which sort algorithm it is using.